# "I only have discovered today" vs. "I only today have discovered" vs. "I have only today discovered"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Since I am not a native English speaker it's hard to find anything related to this topic on google.

Which of the following word orders is grammatical?

> - I **only** have discovered today we have a test tomorrow.
> - I **only** today have discovered we have a test tomorrow.
> - I have **only** today discovered we have a test tomorrow.

Comment: Have you heard about our ELL at ell.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have **only**  discovered today **that** we have a test tomorrow

Comment: @MelkorNemesis How do you know that "that's exactly what I was looking for."?

Comment: Because it's not difficult to assure yourself on google after getting answer from someone?

Answer (score 2):

or

> *I have discovered **only today that** we have a test tomorrow*.

or

> ***Only today** have I discovered **that** we have a test tomorrow*.

I would suggest it might read slightly more easily if the verbal phrase ***have discovered*** is not split.